Why does my deviantart API refresh token keep becoming invalid?
I've been using Excel macros and the deviantart API to find literature and then basically give it a score so I can find good literature. For some reason, I can only use a refresh token once or maybe not even once and then it will say invalid when it tries to use it again. Here's what I've been doing

I'll open this link manually since I don't get a code when I try using a winhttprequest in Excel VBA. The link is https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=redacted&redirect_uri=redacted&scope=browse&state=mysessionid. The response will give me an authorization code

I'll open this link manually for the same reason using the auth code it gave me from the above link https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token?&grant_type=authorization_code&code=redacted&client_id=redacted&client_secret=redacted&redirect_uri=redacted. The response will give me an access code and a refresh code which will let my Excel VBA macro search for an hour.

After the hour runs out, sometimes it works but usually when I winhttprequest this link and ill get refresh code invalid https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=redacted&client_secret=redacted&refresh_token=redacted


Does anybody know why it keeps saying invalid? I can't seem to find anybody else with this same problem and couldn't find an explanation for the error on the deviantart page so I'm not sure who to ask.
EDIT: I'm wondering if this is because I have the ouath2 grant type set to implicit instead of authorization code (I was using implicit at first until I had trouble getting VBA to refresh the access token after an hour) so I'll try changing it to authorization code and see if that works.
